# How do you detect changes in a user's Spotify playlist?

Tags: api, spotify

Scenario: Spotify user on the native desktop application is adding and removing songs from the currently playing playlist.

I'm curious if it's possible for me to detect when any addition/removal happens? Basically need a trigger to tell me the playlist has changed without having to continuously poll Spotify's API to see if anything changed. Looking for a solution that could be used either via the Spotify API or something hack-ish using spotilocal or listening on Spotify's 4070 port.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for a solution that could be used either via the Spotify API
>   or something hack-ish using spotilocal or listening on Spotify's 4070
>   port.

I wouldn't recommend this approach since the mentioned APIs may change without notice. It's not publicly supported so there's no commitment from Spotify to avoid breaking changes. It also requires the user to have the Spotify desktop application installed.

As you've noticed, since there's currently no way to subscribe to changes in a playlist, e.g. by a Websocket or HTTP PubSub interface like [PubSubHubbub](https://github.com/pubsubhubbub), your application would be forced to poll for changes. If you go down this path, I strongly recommend that you make use of the ETags and `snapshot_id` provided in the Playlist response.

Declaring how ETags are implemented in the Web API deserves a longer response and should be on the developer site. There's however a useful [Working With Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/working-with-playlists/) guide on there that explains snapshots and some other things related to playlists.

It's also worth mentioning that all applications are rate limited, so I urge anyone polling to be aware of this and poll less rather than more. Obviously only poll when the application is actively used by the user, and only poll the playlist if it's actively viewed. You know you're being rate limited if you retrieve a 429 Too Many Requests response.